# Update Droid to 2.2 over wifi possible?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, updates

I have a Motorola Droid running 2.1 that does not have Verizon service.  Therefore it does not seem to be getting the over-the-air (OTA) update.  Is there anyway to update this via wifi?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually update your phone by downloading the update.zip file for 2.2, putting it in the root of your SD card and applying the update in the recovery during boot up.

[See detailed instructions here](http://phandroid.com/2010/08/26/manually-update-motorola-droid-to-froyo-frg22d-and-install-flash-10-1/).

Comment: Is this different from what happens when you root your phone to get an update that the manufacturer/service provider hasn't pushed yet?

Comment: Sort-of. What I was describing here is when you take the official OTA update (which comes packaged in a zip file) and drop it in the root of your SD card.  The next time you reboot, your phone knows to look for that file. When you root and apply a non-official OTA update, it is a very similar process but usually involves having to manually flash the zip file to your phone using a recovery (ClockworkRecovery, for example).

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I wonder how I could find the official OTA updates' zip files whenever they become available....

Comment: ...but that's probably its own question. :)

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question at http://support.vzw.com/how_to_use/droid_upgrade.html . It says "If you are roaming, you will not receive a system update notice. You will need to enable Wi-Fi and wait for the update notice to appear or as mentioned above you can manually update by selecting 'Home' > 'Menu' > 'Settings' > 'About phone' > 'System updates'."